# Is there a similar way to access music files on WatchOS as there is for iOS (E.g. MPMediaPickerController)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, watchos

I have been wanting to make a standalone equalizer app for the Apple Watch as I am usually not near my phone while using the Music Player on the Apple Watch. When not near the phone, the equalizer shuts off and this is a pain.

However to do so, I would require access to the local audio library so I could run them through something like AudioKit. This is possible when developing iOS apps, but I cannot find any documentation regarding watchOS.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been looking into this for a mindfulness App I'm playing with. Doesn't look like there is any access to MediaPicker in watchOS.

Whilst Media Player is available in watchOS 5.0+ [see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/https://developer.apple.com/) all the APIs to select tracks appear to be available for iOS and macOS only. See [MPMediaLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmedialibrary) the same being true for MPMediaPickerController.

watchOS 6 brought in the ability to stream, but if you want to play local audio in your App at the moment you must first download/transfer the audio to your App beforehand.